# Returning a Result from a destination from global action

Tags: android, navigation

I found out about returning data using navigation library on [android documents](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/whats-new-in-navigation-2020.html)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
val navController = findNavController();
// We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is 
supported
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String> 
("key")?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
    // Do something with the result.
   }
}
```

and

```
navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

Though, I cannot make it work if I'm using a global action to do the following:
Fragment x -> (global action) Fragment A -> Fragment B -> (popbackstack(A, true)) -> Fragment X

Is that intended or is there another way to deal with this? (I know about viewModels, but just wanted to try the new tech)

edit: added code from docs

Comment: Actually, there is some error in the blog post. Read this article for clear idea- https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `Fragment 1.3.0-alpha04`, each `FragmentManager` implements `FragmentResultOwner`.
You can use `Fragment Result API`. [Android document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between)

```kotlin
import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResultListener
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { key, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
        val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
        // Do something with the result...
    }
}

import androidx.fragment.app.setFragmentResult
button.setOnClickListener {
    val result = "result"
    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
}
```

Comment: I was asking for specifically with the latest navigation technology that came with the last update. And your solution uses alpha version wich I can't use for production. 
I found a solution though

Comment: Any idea as to why the fragment listener has requestKey property, if we only can have result from one single requestKey?

To clarify:
what you set here `setFragmentResultListener("requestKey")`
is what you'll get here
`{ key, bundle ->` in key property
and I don't understand that because you can only set one listener for one result. so why have requestKey there

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: using getBackStackEntry with specific fragmentId to save the results

```
 findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.fragmentId).savedStateHandle.set(
            KEY,
            "Value"
        )
```

getting the results in the previous fragments happens the same way.

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<List<Uri>>(
        ImageViewerFragment.ADDED_IMAGE_KEY
    )?.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner
    ) { result ->
      //do something
      }
```